# Inverse of the following $2\times 2$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I was asked to find the inverse of the following Matrix $A$:

$$\begin{bmatrix}8&-3\\-4&-7\end{bmatrix}$$

I created a new Matrix, $[A|I]$, where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix and row reduced it. I ended up with:

$$\begin{bmatrix}7/68&31/68\\-1/17&-2/17\end{bmatrix}$$

But apparently I'm wrong. Any ideas on how to find the inverse?

Answer (score 1):

Formula for the inverse of a $2$ by $2$ matrix is

$$\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{bmatrix}=\frac{1}{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: by the way, if you would like to know what went wrong... you might like to include your working.

Comment: I don't have photos of my work nor am I able to take photos at the moment. But all I did was row reduce the matrix. I applied the formula and it seems like I was really close; I'll look back at my work and figure out where I went wrong. This formula wouldn't work on a 3x3 matrix right? I have a similar problem except it's with a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: we can always write down formula for another size but we shouldn't spend time memorizing. try to practice doing row operations. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix) shows us the formula for $3 \times 3$ matrix and the general formula using adjoint.

Comment: Of course. As for row reduction though, it's just a matter of taking [A|I] and row reducting until you get [I|A^-1] right?

Comment: And sorry for the poor formatting. I'm relatively new to the site...

Comment: yup, just make the left hand block become the identity matrix using elementary row operations. [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/306553) reference. I am already impressed that you are able to key in a matrix. =)

Answer (score 1):

Setting up the system $[A\mid I]$ and row reducing gives:
$$\begin{bmatrix}8&-3&|&1&0\\-4&-7&|&0&1\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{(1)}\begin{bmatrix}0&-17&|&1&2\\-4&-7&|&0&1\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{(2)}\begin{bmatrix}0&1&|&-1/17&-2/17\\1&7/4&|&0&-1/4\end{bmatrix}$$
where the steps are
$$\begin{align}&(1)\qquad R_2+R_1\mapsto R_1\\&(2)\qquad \begin{cases}-\frac{1}{17}R_1\mapsto R_1\\-\frac{1}{4}R_2\mapsto R_2\end{cases}\end{align}$$
I leave the final step to you, as it is fairly straight forward. Maybe you can spot your mistake from these first couple of steps. This method (i.e. row reducing the system $[A\mid I]$) is a very general method for finding the inverse, so it's good to familiarize yourself with it. However, in the trivial $2\times 2$ case, one often uses the formula that Siong Thye Goh gives.

Comment: @farruhota what do you mean? This process I have above is getting the identity matrix on the left hand side of the augmented system.

Comment: @farruhota yes one would swap the rows at the end, but this is so trivial that it could just be done at the very end or simultaneously with the last significant step.

Comment: @farruhota yes that also works, I just prefer not to add fractions when I can, so the way I did it reduces this.